# meaning of 録(と)り直した?

Tags: translation, anime

In season 3 episode 10 of Kaguya-sama, at 7:12, one of the characters says:

> 何度も録(と)り直したかいがあったわ

(which I found by Japanese subtitles)

I am having trouble understanding this part: 録(と)り直した

I am having trouble finding any words or phrases that this corresponds to in a dictionary.  Any ideas what is being said here?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40854/9831

Comment: This post may indirectly answer the core of your question: [17439/What's with all the possible kanji for とる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17439/). Generally 録る is used for A/D converted data recorded to elec/magnetic media.

Comment: Yes both of these things help, thank you both.